# Azure web app not working - 500

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-core

I really want to use dotnet core and azure. I used the amazing yeoman aspnet generator to scaffold out a basic app. This ran fine locally using Kestrel.

I then added the app to my github account and linked this to a new Azure Web App instance to deploy the thing. But no joy :( I get a 500 error.

Looking at the setting of the webapp it saying using .net framework 4.6 is that right or am I missing something, cannot see an option for .net core 1.0 that I expected to see??

I tried turning on logging in the setting with detailed exceptions etc but have not found anything to give me a clue as to what going on.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy, Could you try access into kudu site(*yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net*) and start web.cmd file in this folder (*`/home/site/approot`*)? I suggest you can try to start this command. Meanwhile, please refer to Shawn's blog 'https://wildermuth.com/2016/04/29/Deploying-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-to-Azure-App-Services '. Any information or update, please let me know.